# What type is meant by SQLDescribeCol when it returns -8?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, odbc

In the code sample below I am getting a `-8` returned in `dataType` for a column in a SQL Server 2012 table that is of type `nchar(10)`.  I can't find `-8` defined anywhere in the header files.  In `sqlext.h` I can find the following negative values defined, but it stops at `-7`.

Apparently `-8` means `nchar(x)`, but is that defined and if so where?

Here is the excerpt from `sqlext.h` defining `-1` through `-7`:

```
#define SQL_LONGVARCHAR                         (-1)
#define SQL_BINARY                              (-2)
#define SQL_VARBINARY                           (-3)
#define SQL_LONGVARBINARY                       (-4)
#define SQL_BIGINT                              (-5)
#define SQL_TINYINT                             (-6)
#define SQL_BIT                                 (-7)
```

Here is my code.  I am concerned with the call to `SQLDescribeColA`:

```
void ODBCulator::setColumns(ODBCResultSet& resultSet, SQLHANDLE hStmt) {
    SQLSMALLINT numCols ;
    SQLRETURN retCode = SQLNumResultCols( hStmt, &numCols ); 
    SQLCHAR colName[1000] ;
    SQLSMALLINT colNameLen, dataType, numDecimalDigits, allowsNullValues ;
    SQLULEN columnSize ; SQL_BIT;
    for( int i = 1 ; i <= numCols ; i++ ) { 
        retCode = SQLDescribeColA( hStmt, i, colName, 
            (sizeof(colName) / sizeof(colName[0])) - 1,
            &colNameLen, &dataType, &columnSize, 
            &numDecimalDigits, &allowsNullValues );
        resultSet.addColumn( i, colName, dataType, columnSize );
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of sources in the internet have `-8` the value for `SQL_WCHAR` type.

```
/*
 *  SQL datatypes - Unicode
 */
#define SQL_WCHAR                   (-8)
#define SQL_WVARCHAR                (-9)
#define SQL_WLONGVARCHAR            (-10)
```

e.g.,

https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/iodbc/iodbc-42.2/iodbc/include/sqlucode.h?txt

or

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openoffice/trunk/main/unixODBC/inc/sqlucode.h

Comment: I can add that to my project's code. What ODBC implementation does that come from?

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick I'm sorry I don't have more information, I got this by doing some quick research on the internet

Comment: Thanks.  I spent an hour searching -8 and SQLDescribeColumn, I got nothing.  Some are better at searching than others.